# "Processus stopped "during prediction after model with vgg model computed

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, keras

I'm currently facing an issue with my `Tensorflow` pipeline.
Don't know if it's specific of `Tensorflow` or Python.

I'm trying to do a confusion matrix afterward my compiled `vgg16` model.
So i used the model object got after the fit method and try to predict the same features to compute my CM.

But the message "Processus arrêté" or process stopped in English appear and the script stop working

Here is the output :

```
    Using TensorFlow backend.
    
    Load audio features and labels : 100%  Time: 0:00:50 528.41  B/s
   VGG16 model with last layer changed
    Number of label: 17322
    Model: "sequential"
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
vgg16 (Functional)           (None, 4, 13, 512)        14713536  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 26624)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 256)               6816000   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257       
=================================================================
Total params: 21,529,793
Trainable params: 13,895,681
Non-trainable params: 7,634,112
_________________________________________________________________
2772/2772 [==============================] - 121s 44ms/step - loss: 0.2315 - acc: 0.9407 - val_loss: 0.0829 - val_acc: 0.9948
Processus arrêté
```

```
Here is the model : 
   

     def launch2(self):
    
            print("VGG16 model with last layer changed")
            x = np.array(self.getFeatures())[...,np.newaxis]
            print("Number of label: " + str(len(self.getLabels())))
    
            vgg_conv=VGG16(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=(128, 431, 1))
    
            #Freeze the layers except the last 4 layers
            for layer in vgg_conv.layers[:-4]:
                layer.trainable = False
    
            #Create the model
            model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential()
    
            #Add the vgg convolutional base model
            model.add(vgg_conv)
    
            opt = Adam(lr=1e-4)
    
            model.add(Flatten())
            model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dropout(0.5))
            model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
    
            model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
            model.summary()
    
            model.fit(x=x,y=self.getLabels(),shuffle=True,batch_size=5,epochs=1, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1)
    
            model.save('vggModelLastLayer.h5')
    
            self.testModel(model,x)

Here is the function which allow me to compute the CM : 


    def testModel(self, model,x):
    
            print("Informations about model still processing. Last step is long")
            y_labels = [int(i) for i in self.getLabels().tolist()]
    
            classes = model.predict_classes(x)
    
            predicted_classes = np.argmax(results, axis=1)
            # Call model info (true labels, predited labels)
    
            #self.modelInfo(y_labels, predicted_classes)
            from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
            from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
            cm=confusion_matrix(y_labels,predicted_classes)
            target_names=["Bulls","No bulls"]
            print(classification_report(y_labels,predicted_classes, target_names=target_names))
            print(cm)


How could I fix this ? Is this a memory leak or something ? 
Thank you in advance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found why this turned out like this

Just because of memory. My memory RAM wasn't enough big to calculate the total amount of data i had